# Error when typing npm start with react app

Tags: reactjs

i installed react-app using: 'npm i -g create-react-app@1.5.2' i installed the same version as tutorial video of react. Then i went into my folder and made a react app using: 'create-react-app react-app' in command prompt. Now when i 'npm start' it gives this error.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\Web\practices\react mosh\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Web\practices\react mosh\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-16T15_31_44_914Z-debug.log
```

this is what my package.json scripts is like:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

i tried other solutions on stackoverflow didn't work.

Comment: Is that your whole `package.json` file ? Because that is not valid JSON.

Comment: Or else you are not in the right directory. There should be a `react-app` directory (maybe `D:\Web\practices\react mosh\react-app`)

Comment: @giuseppedeponte no that is just the scripts in my package.json and i am in the right directory in which i installed the react app and where package.json file is located

Comment: nevermind i had 2 similar folders i was in the wrong folder thanks!